# What do wave crests indicate about a boat's speed?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

[image]

Wave crests spread out behind a boat as shown above. What do the wave crests indicate about the boat's speed?

1. It is increasing.
2. It is less than the speed of the water waves.
3. It is equal to the speed of the water waves.
4. It is greater than the speed of the water waves.
5. The wave crests do not indicate anything about the boat's speed.

Perhaps, since the distance between the crests remains constant, the speed of the boat is equal to the speed of the water waves. But, then if the boat is moving at a constant speed (slower than the speed of water waves), won't the distance between water waves also be constant...?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9482/why-is-the-angle-of-the-wake-of-a-duck-constant). The angle of this Kelvin Wake is *independent* of the speed of the boat. The speed of water waves varies with wavelength.  [Read up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake#Kelvin_wake_pattern).